# How to get only Images from textarea in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a field of textarea by Tinymce. I am inserting images in that field. Now i want to retrieve the images one by one to use them in different div. Is it possible? Right now the result i am getting using this line `{{ $busprice->bus->references }}` is
`<p><img src="http://www.cochinsquare.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/volvo.jpg" /><img src="http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/iipcache/144905.jpg" /></p>`

and if i use `{!! $busprice->bus->references !!}` then i am getting the images as display. 
Any suggestion to get only img tag?

Comment: go with [goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) , or you may use some regex in case if you are trying to extract small set of data

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that will split all `img` tags into an array or a string. You can place the function where you want - but maybe as an additional helper function.
My example is a function like that

```
function getImageTags($string, $result = 'string') {
    if (preg_match_all('/<img([\w\W]+?)\/>/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        if ($result == 'array') {
            $array = '';

            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                $array[] = $match;
            }

            return $array;
        } else {
            $string = '';

            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                $string .= $match[0];
            }

            return $string;
        }
    }

    if ($result == 'array') {
        return [];
    }

    return '';
}
```

As helper function declared you can use it in a view of Laravel like this

```
{!! getImageTags($busprice->bus->references) !!}
```